# Sending messages back to a client

Tags: c#, client-server, message

I have a client-server applications I wrote in c#.
My server monitors the commands sent to it by the client.
I wish to send a "finish" message back to the client when the process finishes, I'm just not sure how to do it...

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace RM
{
    public partial class RMFORM : Form
    {
        private Socket clientSock;
        private string userName = "";
        private string testName = "";
        private string testNameString = "";
        private string targetPath = "";
        private bool isConnected = false;
        private TestForm testForm;
        private List<string> listOfFilesToCopy = new List<string>();
        private List<string> listOfPathToCopy = new List<string>();
        private RegistryKey registryKey;

        public RMFORM ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            userName = RemoteUtils.getConnectedUser();
            targetPath = RemoteUtils.targetPath + userName;
            testForm = new TestForm(RemoteUtils.remoteIpAddress, userName);
        }

        private void createNewCommand(string executable, string selectedPath, bool isDirectory)
        {
            string selectedOutDir = "";

            testForm.enableFinishedButton();
            testForm.setNumOfProcessesTest();
            testForm.ShowDialog();

            while (!testForm.getIsFinished())
            {
                if (testForm.getIsFormClosed())
                {
                    testForm.Hide();
                    return;
                }
            }

            testName = testForm.getTestName();
            testNameString = testForm.getSelectedTestType();
            selectedOutDir = targetPath + "\\" + testName;

            try
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(selectedOutDir))
                {
                    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Test named " + testName + " already exists.\nDo You Wish To Continue?", "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(selectedOutDir);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
                this.Close();
            }

            if (testNameString.CompareTo("Mek") == 0)
            {
                addSingleTest(executable, selectedPath, selectedOutDir, "mek", isDirectory);
            }
            if (testNameString.CompareTo("Mel") == 0)
            {
                addSingleTest(executable, selectedPath, selectedOutDir, "mel", isDirectory);
            }
            if (testNameString.CompareTo("Mem") == 0)
            {
                addSingleTest(executable, selectedPath, selectedOutDir, "mem", isDirectory);
            }


        }
        private void addSingleTest(string executable, string selectedPath, string outputDir, string testType, bool isDirectory)
        {
            string commandToRun = "";

            commandToRun = targetPath + RemoteUtils.batchRunPath + executable + testForm.getTestPerformance() + " " + selectedPath + " " + outputDir;
            if (!isDirectory)
            {
                commandToRun += "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(selectedPath) + "." + testType + ".pos " + testType;
            }
            else
            {
                commandToRun += " " + testType + " " + testForm.getNumOfProcess();
            }

            removeOne.Enabled = true;
            removeAll.Enabled = true;
            sendBtn.Enabled = true;

            listORequestedCommands.Items.Add(commandToRun);
            listORequestedCommands.Refresh();
        }
        private bool searchForFiles(string parentDirectory)
        {
            bool found = false;

            if (Directory.GetFiles(parentDirectory, "*" + RemoteUtils.sequenceExtenssion).Length > 0)
                return true;

            try
            {
                foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(parentDirectory))
                {
                    if (Directory.GetFiles(subDir, "*" + RemoteUtils.sequenceExtenssion).Length > 0)
                        return true;
                    found = searchForFiles(subDir);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
                this.Close();
            }

            return found;

        }
        private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!isConnected)
                {
                    registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(RemoteUtils.registrySubKey);
                    clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    connectBtn.Text = "Disconnect From Server";
                    connectBtn.Refresh();
                    clientSock.Connect(RemoteUtils.remoteIpAddress, RemoteUtils.remotePort);
                    statusColor.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    statusColor.Refresh();
                    isConnected = true;
                    buttonAddDirectory.Enabled = true;
                    buttonAddFile.Enabled = true;
                    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
                    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender1, e1) => RemoteUtils.copyDllsToServer(targetPath);
                    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    registryKey.Close();
                    connectBtn.Text = "Connect To Server";
                    isConnected = false;
                    statusColor.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    buttonAddDirectory.Enabled = false;
                    buttonAddFile.Enabled = false;
                    clientSock.Close();
                    clientSock.Dispose();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
                this.Close();
            }

        }
        private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string [] commandsInRegistry = registryKey.GetValueNames();

                for (int i = 0; i < commandsInRegistry.Length; i++)
                {
                    registryKey.DeleteValue(commandsInRegistry[i]);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < listORequestedCommands.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    clientSock.Send(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(listORequestedCommands.Items[i].ToString() + " <eom> "));
                    registryKey.SetValue("Command " + (i + 1).ToString(), listORequestedCommands.Items[i].ToString());
                }

                removeAll_Click(sender, e);
                sendBtn.Enabled = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
                this.Close();
            }

        }
        private void buttonAddDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = "C:\\";

            if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedPath = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;

                if (!searchForFiles(selectedPath))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The directory: " + selectedPath + " doesn't contain sequences.", "Error!");
                    return;
                }

                testForm.enableNumOfProcesses();
                createNewCommand(RemoteUtils.runBatchScript, selectedPath, true);
            }
        }
        private void buttonAddFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "PMD files (*" + RemoteUtils.sequenceExtenssion + ")|*" + RemoteUtils.sequenceExtenssion + "|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedFile = openFileDialog.FileName;
                if (Path.GetExtension(selectedFile).CompareTo(RemoteUtils.sequenceExtenssion) != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The file: " + selectedFile + " is not a sequence file.", "Error!");
                    return;
                }
                createNewCommand(RemoteUtils.batchRunExe, selectedFile, false);
            }
        }
        private void removeOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int iRemoveIndex = listORequestedCommands.SelectedIndex;
            if (iRemoveIndex > -1)
            {
                listORequestedCommands.Items.RemoveAt(iRemoveIndex);
                listORequestedCommands.Refresh();
                if (listORequestedCommands.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    removeOne.Enabled = false;
                    removeAll.Enabled = false;
                    sendBtn.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
        private void removeAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listORequestedCommands.Items.Clear();
            listORequestedCommands.Refresh();
            buttonAddDirectory.Enabled = true;
            buttonAddFile.Enabled = true;
            removeOne.Enabled = false;
            removeAll.Enabled = false;
            sendBtn.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at

http://www.thecodeproject.com/csharp/ZaSocks5Proxy.asp

We use code based on this in our s/w so that our "server" monitors input to broadcasts the message to all other users hooked into the "server"

In essence each workstation monitors in incoming string. The first word of the string we use as a "command" and process accordingly. "finish" could be such a command.